# What is the “Defective effect” like?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I would like to translate this sentence below into Japanese, but I don’t know what “the defective effect” in the sentence means like.

“As some psychologists point out the unhappy experience in one's childhood has a defective effect on his later life.”

1,Does this sentence sounds natural? If there are unnatural points, I would like to know them.

2,What is ”defective effect”?

I know that the usage of “defective” like, “I think that theory is defective.”,but I can’t understand what will be lacked from “his later life”.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *Defective* is entirely the wrong word here. If an effect is defective, it is not effective -- it has no effect. It is quite literally a contradiction in terms. You appear to have asked this question [elsewhere](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/16654924) in a forum which allows discussion (unlike Stack Exchange). You need to go back to the author and ask what they mean.

Comment: In this context, *defective* most likely means *harmful* or *negative*. It would be helpful if you could provide a reference to the actual source of the sentence.